# How to save `std::vector<uchar>` into `std::ostream`?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, ostream

We have created and filled some `std::vector<uchar>`  with [openCV `imencode`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html) for example. Now we want to stream it for example into some http_lib which can take some sort of  [ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/) (ostringstream) for example, or we just want to save in while we debug our programm with ofstream. So I wonder how to put   `std::vector<uchar>` into `std::ostream`?

Comment: Probably by iterating the elements and streaming each one in individually.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`write`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/):

```
void send_data(std::ostream & o, const std::vector<uchar> & v)
{
  o.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(v.data()), v.size());
}
```

The ostream expects naked `char`s, but it's fine to treat uchars as those by casting that pointer. On older compilers you may have to say `&v[0]` instead of `v.data()`.

You can return the result of `write()` as another `std::ostream&` or as a `bool` if you like some error checking facilities.

Comment: +10 For taking the probable chance of a non-C++11 compiler into account. And +1 for the actual answer, of course.

Comment: @ChristianRau: I take it that was a binary +10 :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you want the output formatted, you might be able to use `copy` in conjunction with `ostream_iterator`:

```
#include <iterator>

/*...*/

copy( v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<uchar>(my_stream,"") );
```